# Mouse Dragging Logic

Tags: java, logic

Here is some code which makes a `GCompound` move correctly with dragging.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    currentLabel.setLocation(e.getX()+DX, e.getY()+DY);
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
    currentLabel = (coolLabel) getElementAt(e.getX(),e.getY());
    DX = currentLabel.getX()-e.getX();
    DY = currentLabel.getY()-e.getY();
    currentLabel.sendToFront();
}
```

Here it is without it moving correctly:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    currentLabel.move(e.getX()+DX, e.getY()+DY);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
    currentLabel = (coolLabel) getElementAt(e.getX(),e.getY());
    DX = -e.getX();
    DY = -e.getY();
    currentLabel.sendToFront();
}
```

Can someone explain why this is so? Seems both versions of my code are using the same thinking... Basically in the first case I take the original `GObject` and **set** its location based on the difference from my original position, and in the second case I **move** the original object based on the difference from my original position.

Answer (score 0):

`move()` is a deprecated synonym of `setLocation()`.

The reason one doesn't work and the other does is that you feed different parameters into it. (Specifically in the second case you always call `move(0,0)`.)

A snippet from the `java.awt.Component` source code confirms this:

```
public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    move(x, y);
}

@Deprecated
public void move(int x, int y) {
    synchronized(getTreeLock()) {
        setBoundsOp(ComponentPeer.SET_LOCATION);            
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I think that actually when I drag the mouse I don't call `move(0,0)`; I call precisely the difference between my new `x,y` location and my original which gives me the **delta**.  So yes while the `move` method is similar to the set location it doesn't make sense yet to me why it doesn't move the object's location.

Comment: @Steven I'm afraid you're wrong. You calculate DX as `DX = -e.getX();`, then you call `move()` with `e.getX() + DX`, which is `e.getX() -e.getX()`, which is zero. And like the code I copied for you shows, `move()` isn't similar to `setLocation()`, it is exactly the same method under a different name.

Comment: Is this correct: When I press the mouse, it records initial values (negative of course) for my mouse location.  When I drag the mouse, it holds the same initial values for DX and DY and adds them to the new e.getX() etc... so shouldn't I be moving by some non-zero value?  My thoughts are that if you are correct here, then what's to change in the logic with the first example.  It seems I am using the same logic in both cases.

Comment: @Steven Try exactly the same code as your first example but substitute `move()` for `setLocation()`. You will find that it behaves exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

While the first example sets `DX` and `DY` relatively to your current label location, the second example ignores the current location of the current location of your label.

For example, if your current label location is (50,50) and you want to move it by (30,30). if you press the mouse when pointing to (70,70) (assuming it's within the label boundries):

In your first example DX will be set to -20 and DY will be set to -20. Now, after the drag the new location will be (as `mouseDragged` implements) ((70+30)-20, (70+30)-20) = (80, 80) which is correct.

In your second example DX will be set to -70, as well as DY. Now, after the drag, the new location will be (100-70, 100-70) = (30,30) which is wrong.

Comment: Notice that in the second case, I am not **setting the location, I am simply moving the object** using the `move` method.  So yes, I should be moving the object by (30,30) which is indeed correct.  So this does not help me.

Comment: @Steven You **are** setting the location, whatever you may think.

Comment: @biziclop Yes I am setting the location, but I am setting the location to be `e.getX() - old value for e.getX() + currentLabel.get(X)